# Ruby ActiveMQ Stomp consumer doesn't print message

Tags: ruby, jms, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm using Ruby STOMP to send messages to ActiveMQ.

Producer Code//consumer.rb

```
client = Stomp::Client.new("user", "pass", "localhost", 61613)
client.publish("/queue/mine", "hello world!")
```

Consumer Code//consumer.rb

```
client = Stomp::Client.new("user", "pass", "localhost", 61613)
client.subscribe("/queue/mine") do |msg|
    p msg.body
end
```

But, Ruby consumer consumes messages fine, it doesn't Print anything. Ideally it should be printing, "hello world!". 
Any help or pointers are most welcome.

Comment: Which stomp client library are you using?

Comment: @RobNewton thank you for looking into it, I'm using `stompgem/stomp`, https://github.com/stompgem/stomp, I got further clue, its not printing because my producers is producing `BinaryMessage`, rather then `TextMessage`, If you could help that will be great.

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving messages?  Rather than printing msg.body, can you just print a static test string to prove your callback block is being called.